# No Ping Through Cisco Trunks

Tags: cisco, trunk

I am trying to ping on my management VLAN across a trunk between 2 Cisco switches. Both switches have the following configs

```
interface TenGigabitEthernt1/1/1
switchport trunk native vlan 5
switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,20-21,30,40,50-51
switchport mode trunk
switchport nonegotiate
spanning-tree guard root
service policy output QOS_POLICY_SWITCHPORT
ip dhcp snooping trust
```

Both switches have the same config for the fiber port connecting each other. Both switches have an address on VLAN 10. But for some reason I can't ping? What am I missing?

Comment: Start at layer-1. Is the physical link up?

Comment: `show spanning-tree vlan 10` on both sides.

Comment: @RonMaupin Yes link light is on the SFP port

Comment: @RonTrunk Spanning Tree instance(s) for vlan 10 does not exist.

Comment: Create VLAN 10 with the global `vlan 10` command. That is not the same as creating the VLAN 10 interface with the `interface Vlan10` command.

Comment: @RonMaupin that's weird now it is working. Why wasn't it working before when it showed teh VLAN existed when I was running show vlan

Comment: I am also getting Root Guard blocking  the port. Why is that?

Comment: You can't have both ports with root guard -- One of them isn't the root

Comment: Ahh that was it! Stupid me. Thank!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved. Forgot that one of them should not have `spanning-tree guard root` because it is the root.

Comment: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/55118/8499